# If $f$ is continuous on a compact subset $X$, then $f(X)$ is also a compact subset. ("Mathematical Analysis 2nd Edition" by Tom M. Apostol)

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am reading "Mathematical Analysis 2nd Edition" by Tom M. Apostol.

> **Theorem 4.25.** Let $f : S \to T$ be a function from one metric space $(S, d_S)$ to another $(T, d_T)$. If $f$ is continuous on a compact subset $X$ of $S$, then the image $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $T$; in particular, $f(X)$ is closed and bounded in $T$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $F$ be an open covering of $f(X)$, so that $f(X) \subseteq \bigcup_{A \in F} A$. We will show that a finite number of the sets $A$ cover $f(X)$. Since $f$ is continuous on the metric subspace $(X, d_S)$ we can apply Theorem 4.23 to conclude that each set $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $(X, d_S)$. The sets $f^{-1}(A)$ form an open covering of $X$ and, since $X$ is compact, a finite number of them cover $X$, say
> $$X \subseteq f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p).$$
> Hence
> \begin{align*}
> f(X) &\subseteq f[f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p)] \\
> &= f[f^{-1}(A_1)] \cup \cdots \cup f[f^{-1}(A_p)] \\
> &\subseteq A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_p,
> \end{align*}
> so $f(X)$ is compact. As a corollary of Theorem 3.38, we see that $f(X)$ is closed and bounded.

The author wrote the following sentence.
I think that $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq X$ doesn't hold in general.

> Since $f$ is continuous on the metric subspace $(X, d_S)$ we can apply Theorem 4.23 to conclude that each set $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $(X, d_S)$.

And if we interpret $f^{-1}(A)$ as $f|_T^{-1}(A)$, then we can write $$X = f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p)$$ instead of $$X \subseteq f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \cdots \cup f^{-1}(A_p).$$

Is the author's proof right?

Comment: The preimage of A is by definition a subset of the domain, so I don't see any issue with Apostol's argument.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thank you very much for your comment. The domain is $S$ and not $X$. So the preimage of $A$ is a subset of $S$ and not a subset of $X$ in general.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Then you are right. As a side comment, I think this theorem is clumsily stated, since there is no notion of relative compactness, we do not need to worry about what larger space the compactum is in.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, $f^{-1}(A)\subseteq X$ is in general not true. There are two ways to get a correct proof.

1. Change the assumption "$f$ is continuous on $X$" to "$f$ is continuous". Then we correctly get

> ... each set $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $(S, d_S)$.

2. Take it literally that $f$ is continuous on $X$. This means that $f_X = f \mid_X : (X,d_S) \to (T,d_T)$ is continuous although it is possible that $f$ is not continuous in all points of $S$. Then we know that $(f_X)^{-1}(A)$ is open in $X$. By Theorem 3.33 there exists an open $U_A  \subset S$ such that $U_A \cap X = (f_X)^{-1}(A)$. The $U_A$ form an open covering of $X$ in $S$. Now use the compactness of $X$ to get finitely many $A_i$ such that the $U_{A_i}$ cover $X$. This implies that the $(f_X)^{-1}(A_i)$ cover $X$.

In my opinion Apostol's approach to define compactness is not the optimal way. He defines compact subsets $X$ of metric spaces $(M,d)$, so it seems that the ambient space $M$ plays a role. This is not the case, it suffices to define

> A metric space $(M,d)$ is compact if each open covering of $M$ contains a finite subcover.

This is an "absolute property" of metric spaces, we do not need a
a bigger ambient $M' \supset M$.

Using this concept a subset $X$ of metric space $(M,d)$ is called a *compact subset* if the metric subspace $(X,d)$ of $(M,d)$ is compact.  It is now a *theorem* that a subset $X$ is compact in this sense if and only if it is compact in Apostol's sense. The proof is easy; the basic idea was used in 2. above. Actually this is the essence of Exercise 3.38.

If we use the "new definition", then the proof of Theorem 4.25 becomes much more transparent.

Comment: Kritiker der Elche, Thank you very much for your answer. $f$ is continuous on $X$ but is not continuous on $S$, so $f^{-1}(A)$ is not open is $(S,d_S)$ in general.

Comment: Let $f : S \to T$ be a function from one metric space $(S, d_S)$ to another $(T, d_T)$. If $f$ is continuous on $S$ and $X$ is a compact subset of $S$, then the image $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $T$; in particular, $f(X)$ is closed and bounded in $T$. Is this a correct statement of Theorem 4.25?

Comment: @tchappyha You are right, I ignored that $f$ has to be continuous only on $X$. See my update.

Comment: Kritiker der Elche, Thank you very much for your comment and answer.